# Disabling the taskbar thumbnail preview functionality for a C# application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, taskbar

Windows has a functionality of thumbnail preview, allowing the user to see a preview screenshot of the application when hovered over on the taskbar.

Is there any way to disable the thumbnail preview that pops up completely? I want there to have no popup/preview at all.

I've tried overriding the thumbnail through DwmSetIconicThumbnail, filling the HBITMAP with a zeroed IntPtr. However that just creates a infinite loading thumbnail.

```
DwmSetIconicThumbnail(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```